# Undo a fast-forward merge

Tags: git

I've made some changes to my git repo that I wish to undo.

My git repo looked like this:

```
A-B----     master
   \   /
    C-D     * develop
```

I was on the `develop` branch, forgot that it differed from the `master` branch, made a change on `develop`, merged it into `master`, and then pushed to my remote (called `publish`).

Because there were no changes on master since B (common ancestor), git did a fast-forward merge.

Now, my repo looks like this:

```
A-B-C-D   master, develop, remotes/publish/master, remotes/publish/develop.
```

I wanted to revert the last merge, restoring `master` to B.

From what I read in [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit), I used `git reset sha-of-B` to restore my `master` branch to revision B.

Questions:

- How do I restore `develop` to revision D?
- How do I then push these changes back to remote/publish?

Comment: Blog post summarising and going in to a bit more detail as to what I did, should've done and how I fixed this: http://www.capnfabs.net/software/git-undoing-a-fast-forward-merge-when-you-shouldve-just-used-a-new-branch/

Comment: @SnowCrash updated link: http://capnfabs.net/blog/2013/01/14/git-undoing-a-fast-forward-merge/

Comment: For sole developers this is probably all good, but for those collaborating, wouldn't it make more sense to use `revert` rather than `reset`?

Comment: @Snowcrash: `git revert -m 1 hashValue` would fail with message that hashValue is not  an merge. Because it is fast forward  merge.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you reset the branch master, it won't touch develop branch. In order to reput all in order, you should do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard sha-of-B
git checkout develop
git reset --hard sha-of-D
git checkout master
git merge develop --no-ff
```

Comment: @SimonBoudrias: Never recommend `push --force`. Use `git push publish --force-with-lease` instead.

Answer (score 35):

- imagine you are still on *master* where you merged and pushed
- `git reset --hard @{1}`

  - this resets branch *“master”* to where it was one step back on your computer (i.e. at “B”)
- for *develop* do nothing, because it should still be at “D”
- `git push publish develop`

  - this pushes branch *“develop”* in the usual way
- `git push publish master --force-with-lease`

  - pushes branch *“master”* backwards, with the permission gained via `--force-with-lease` in a safe way
  - the use of `--force` might *silently* overwrite work from others,
    so I never use that
- or both push operations together with this surprising syntax:

  - `git push publish develop --force-with-lease=master`

Comment: The "git reset --hard @{1}" worked perfect for my situation. I --no-ff a merge and it had 100+ commits and didn't wanna have to to do a soft reset for each one. Thanks! +1

Comment: I accidently did a `git checkout develop && git merge -` instead of a `git checkout develop && git merge --no-ff -` (the - denotes the last branch). The above answer worked very well for me, as I didn't do anything in between and was still on develop: `git reset --hard @{1} && git merge --no-ff feature/my-feature-branch`

Comment: As a usability/confidence tip for this: It might help to `git checkout @{1}` and make sure the current branch and history looks like you want it to, before making the big change to reset things at that commit.

Comment: What does "publish" do in `git push publish`? I don't see that word in the git-push docs or by Googling "git publish".

Comment: @Noumenon That is the name of the repository as established in the question. In the `git push` man page referred to as `<repository>`.

Answer (score 0):

If seems that you were checked out to `develop` when you ran `git reset`, and this is what messed you up.

You can fix `develop` as follows:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only D
```

Now, you can restore `master` back to B:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard B
```

Get back to `develop` and push it:

```
git checkout develop
git push develop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was definitely on the `master` branch, I was just reading the `gitk` gui wrong. I'll edit my question accordingly.